# If same value in one column in tow rows, update another column with same value from one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Writing SQL in MS SQL server management studio.

I have this problem now, I have a table with where there are two of each row with almost identical values:

```
code  |   name   | location  |  group
1     |   Thing  |  1        |  1
1     |   Thing  |  2        |  NULL
```

I need to update the NULL GROUP to match the group that has a value, where the code is the same.

Currently in this form:

```
code    Locationid  ItemGroup2
100001  1           TTE
100001  2           NULL
100002  1           TTG
100002  2           NULL
```

I would like to update the table to match:

```
code    Locationid  ItemGroup2
100001  1           TTE
100001  2           TTE
100002  1           TTG
100002  2           TTG
```

Comment: And what if multiple non-null groups exist per code, which should it use?

Comment: There are two of each code row, with locations 1 and 2. Location 1 has a non-null group and location 2 has a null group.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option `joining` the table to itself:

```
update t1
set grp = t2.grp
from yourtable t1
  join yourtable t2 on t1.code = t2.code and t2.grp is not null
where t1.grp is null
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(grp) over (partition by code) as maxgrp
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set grp = maxgrp
    where grp is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This UPDATE statement should find the first non-null value of `group` for each `code`, so it should be more robust than simply assuming there will only ever be one non-null value.

```
UPDATE b
SET b.[group]=a.[group]
FROM MyTable b
JOIN (
    SELECT [code], [group], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [code]) as rk
    FROM MyTable WHERE [group] IS NOT NULL
) a ON a.[code]=b.[code] AND a.[rk]=1
```